# Can anything else send emails except sp_send_dbmail?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sp-send-dbmail

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I plan to enable emails on a staging server to make sure everything performs as planned before going live.  I'd like all emails that are being sent to come to my own email address and not go to real clients, so I've hardcoded the to, cc, and bcc fields in [sp_send_dbmail] so that it can only send to me, regardless of the parameters being passed in.

The technet page at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189635.aspx only mentions sp_send_dbmail, and I know xp_sendmail is no longer available, so I just want to be sure nothing can be emailed to clients before enabling email on this server.

So before I enable emails, does anyone know of any other SPs or XPs that can send emails that I may not have considered?

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, what do you mean by "everything performs as planned"?

Comment: I was just meaning that, as this is a staging server, and we are currently restructuring it heavily, we'd like it to behave as close to prod as possible, but with this new structure.  To verify everything, including emails, I want emails to be able to be sent without throwing errors, but only to an internal group, not actual customers.  This should let us see what emails are being sent and when.  Some people wont have access to SSMS, and even if they did, wouldn't know how to use it, so I'd like to show them exactly what is happening.  The best way to do this is to send them the emails.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved now, for anyone else looking for a solution to the same question though ...

It seems everything that sends emails, or is involved with emails in SQL Server 2012 revolves around [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail] (previous versions of SQL Server also had xp_sendmail).

So you can edit [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail], just after the BEGIN statement, you insert the following:

```
 SET    @recipients = 'YOURDEVEMAIL@ADDRESSHERE.com'
 SET    @copy_recipients = NULL
 SET    @blind_copy_recipients = NULL
 SET    @subject = '(STAGING EMAIL) ' + ISNULL(@subject, '')
```

Then you will be hijacking any recipients of emails being sent through SQL and sending the email to the address you provide, meaning nothing goes out to customers, etc.

You also need to consider CLRs though, and xp_cmdshell.

For anyone not familiar with these, CLRs are compiled assemblies written in some other programming language that can be called and executed from SQL, and xp_cmdshell runs a command shell from within SQL.

CLRs can be found in SSMS by opening the DB in question in the explorer pane, go to Programmability > Assemblies, and any existing assemblies are in there, however these have already been compiled, this just lets you see if any exist.  You'll need to find the source code for these elsewhere, speak to whoever developed them, they should have it saved somewhere (hopefully).

xp_cmdshell can execute anything you can execute in a Windows command shell, so it could be calling other programs or batch files which could be initiating emails.  You'll need to search for anything calling xp_cmdshell yourself, RedGate SQL Search is good for helping with this.

Answer (score 0):

So these are the two options I could think of:

1) Wrap sp_send_dbmail in your own stored procedure and check whether it is a test server and then replace TO, CC and BCC with a test account.

2.) You probably should not have live data on your test server, therefore just set-up your test data with test email accounts.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not checking to see if sp_send_dbmail works, I'm trying to catch anything else that may send emails out, I've already changed sp_send_dbmail so that it can't send emails to anyone other than myself.  For point (2), I don't have the option of having test data on the staging server, this is for a large series of changes that involve DB structure and app code, there is far too much involved to make up test data, and it needs to be checked against the current production system to make sure everything mirrors accordingly when the same changes are applied to both.